# NullpointerException mocking the test

Tags: java, testing, nullpointerexception, mockito

I have a problem mocking the test, everything goes correct till this point of the code/test which i get a `NullPointerException`, this is the main code where launches the null pointer.

```
ResponseSrvAddDto responseSrvAdd = kjidR048.executeAddDocuments(requestAdd);
        
String returnCode = responseSrvAdd.getReturnCode();
if (returnCode != null && "00".equals(returnCode)){
```

```
ERROR! java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I have this in the test

```
ResponseSrvAddDto responseSrvAdd = mock(ResponseSrvAddDto.class);

Mockito.when(kjidR048.executeAddDocuments(requestAdd)).thenReturn(responseSrvAdd); (this goes correct)
String code = "00";
Mockito.when(responseSrvAdd.getReturnCode()).thenReturn(code);
```

(but this looks like ignores the mock)

I don't know why having the mock in the `responseSrvAdd.getReturnCode()` launches a null pointer but i have this already mocked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: How do you know the first part "goes correct"? If you get a NullPointer on the code you show, that can only come from `responseSrvAdd` being `null`.

Comment: did you check mock invocation happening or not? try printing the mock invocations

Comment: Pls show requestAdd type. Did you implement equals? Is the requestAdd in test equal to requestAdd in method under test? Alternatively, check if argument matcher helps.`any()` is a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

When you use mock on service it's create a object that do nothing or return null on all method. If you want to test `responseSrvAdd.getReturnCode()` use spy https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-spy here is guide.

For entity you need to create object it will be like this:

ResponseSrvAddDto responseSrvAdd = new ResponseSrvAddDto();
responseSrvAdd.setReturnCode("00");
Mockito.when(kjidR048.executeAddDocuments(requestAdd)).thenReturn(responseSrvAdd);

Comment: i have done this, and still getting nullpointerexception          ResponseSrvAddDto responseSrvAddSpy = Mockito.spy(responseSrvAdd);
  responseSrvAddSpy.setReturnCode("00");
  Mockito.verify(responseSrvAddSpy).setReturnCode("00");

Comment: Wait you ResponseSrvAddDto it's just a entity, create object of ResponseSrvAddDto and return it in this moment when(kjidR048.executeAddDocuments(requestAdd)).thenReturn(responseSrvAdd)
And verify() method check that method was called. User assertions for check that value correct.

Comment: thats how i have it, but the problem is in the Mockito.when(responseSrvAddSpy.getReturnCode()).thenReturn("00");, but the whole code is as you mention, as i said, it looks like ignore the mockito.when(), but i already test the kjid call and its going well, just the second one, when i call to the getReturnCode()